# Apache Modcluster failed to drain active sessions

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6, mod-cluster

I'm am using JBoss EAP 6.2 as Webapplication server and Apace Modcluster for load balancing.

Whenever I try to undeploy my webapplication, I get the following warning

```
14:22:16,318 WARN  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 136) MODCLUSTER000025: Failed to drain 2 remaining active sessions from default-host:/starrassist within 10.000000.1 seconds
14:22:16,319 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 136) MODCLUSTER000021: All pending requests drained from default-host:/starrassist in 10.002000.1 seconds
```

and it takes forever to undeploy and the EAP server-group and node in which the application is deployed becomes unresponsive.

The only workaround is to restart the entire EAP server. My Question is, Is there an attribute that I can set in EAP or ModCluster so that the active sessions beyond a maxTimeOut would expire itself?

Answer (score 0):

To control the timeout to stop a context you can use the following configuration value:

> **Stop Context Timeout**
>
> The amount of time, measure in units specified by
>   `stopContextTimeoutUnit`, for which to wait for clean shutdown of a
>   context (completion of pending requests for a distributable context;
>   or destruction/expiration of active sessions for a non-distributable
>   context).
>
> **CLI Command:**
>
> ```
> /profile=full-ha/subsystem=modcluster/mod-cluster-config=configuration/:write-attribute(name=stop-context-timeout,value=10)
> ```

Ref:  [Configure the mod_cluster Subsystem](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Configure_the_mod_cluster_Subsystem.html)

Likewise if you are using JDK 8 take a look at this issue: [Draining pending requests fails with Oracle JDK8](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1161079)